# How to pull all rows containing the same date into a new sheet in OpenOffice Calc

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have 15 spreadsheets (one for each client); each has a column for the date and then additional information in the other columns such as 'action' and 'time spent'. This allows me to see all the work I have done for each client and on which date.

### SHEET 1

```
4/22    Smith      Wrote a letter       30 minutes
4/24    Smith      Phone conversation   20 minutes
5/1     Smith      Meeting              60 minutes
```

### SHEET 2

```
4/22    Jones      Travel time          20 minutes
4/24    Jones      Meeting              60 minutes
```

I want to be able to pull all rows with a certain date into a new spreadsheet, for the time spent on different clients for that day. So I would have a spreadsheet for each day that I worked, and need a way to pull out all rows with that date from the 15 client spreadsheets

### New Sheet (for 4/22)

```
4/22     Smith     wrote a letter       30 minutes
4/22     Jones     travel time          20 minutes
```